# How to build small springboot app using node-red

Tags: java, spring-boot, node-red

I did not understand how to run **spring boot app** using **Node-red** platform.

Simple **spring boot app** code is shown in the link below

https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-boot-hello-world-example

I have downloaded "**java function node**" and "**jar function node**" in node-red, but I did not understand how this example is used in Node-red.

If possible can anyone please guide me how to design or run this "**spring boot**" app using **Node-red**.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

Sprint Boot is a Java framework.

Node-RED is a JavaScript/NodeJS application.